# UK VISA Query for an indian citizen

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I have a valid UK visa from 15 june to 15 december and I have travelled once on that visa and I am in my resident country now and will travel to london in January but I willl leave my residence country in November. So, how can I get my UK visa done as for now my this visa is valid but by the time I will visit the UK in January my visa will be expired and also I can't get it as I won't be in my resident country.

Can I apply for new visa in October for travel in January while I have one of my visa valid.

Comment: @aliawan second time … please, it really is not much of a hassle to at least capitalise *I*s …

Answer (score 7):

From the UK's pages for the [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa):

> The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel.

Since you wish to travel in January, you can apply in October.  Unless you're planning to travel to the UK in *late* January and to leave your country of residence in *early* November, you will probably have enough time to lodge your application.